# Object Data Member is Instantiated Automatically

Tags: c++

I'm getting this super bazar bug in my code that I can't figure out. Basically what's happening is the data member 'char_string' is being created without me even assigning anything to it. It prints out "test123", when in the process.cpp file, I haven't copied the data to it yet.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "process.h"



int main(){

    char string[] = "test123";

    w1::CString test(string);


    return 0;
}
```

**process.h**

```
#ifndef PROCESS_H
#define PROCESS_H

namespace w1{

    class CString{

        private:

            int num_of_chars;
            char char_string[];

        public:
            CString(char *);

    };

}

#endif
```

**process.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "process.h"

w1::CString::CString(char * c_string){

    std::cout << char_string << std::endl;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
test123
```

Comment: You really shouldn't be printing an uninitialized zero-sized array

Comment: It produces the same result when I write stuff to it as well. I simplified the process.cpp constructor to simplify my question. I don't understand how the parameter can possible be copied over to the data member.

Comment: Thats exactly it. Why is it 'test123' when it should be empty. Right but why is c_string equal to char_string? One is a parameter and the other is a data member. Where is the copy that causes char_string to print out 'test123'? Sorry if this is a total miss by me.

Comment: @juanchopanza it first got me as well, but c_string != char_string

Comment: So, it is undefined behaviour. You can't expect the program to do anything specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not instantiated. According to http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/classes/,

> For members of fundamental types, it makes no difference which of the
>   ways above the constructor is defined, because they are not
>   initialized by default, but for member objects (those whose type is a
>   class), if they are not initialized after the colon, they are
>   default-constructed.

Pointers (and thus arrays) are fundamental types, so they are not default constructed if uninitialized. They will point to some memory location, and using that location will result in undefined behavior. In this case you are seeing it happen to point to an actual (and relevant) memory location, but it could just as easily point to 0 (nullptr) or any other value. You might need to look in the internals of your compiler to learn why, but in general you should never depend on such undefined behavior.